# What is the use of converting Array to ArrayList if it is not supporting adding or removing element?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have tried the following and saw it throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` when I try to add new element to it.

Basically I tried to convert an Array to an ArrayList and tried to add new element to it after concerting from array to ArrayList.

my program is :

```
public class ArrayToList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] asset = {"equity", "stocks", "gold", "foreign exchange","fixed income", "futures", "options"}; 
        List<String>  assetList = Arrays.asList(asset);

        for (String object : assetList) {
            System.out.println("object : "+object);
        }

        assetList.add("test");
    }

}
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at anto.com.collection.ArrayToList.main(ArrayToList.java:15)
```

What is the use of converting from array to Arraylist if we are not able to add or remove element from converted value?

Thanks

Comment: All, Thanks for the answers posted. :)

Comment: Notice, this is an example of bad API, which allows to do things, which should be forbidden by construction. It would be much better in the sense of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), if we could use some interface with get/set and without add/etc to achieve random-access polymorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) - returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. You can't add new element on fixed size `List`. To add new element  define `List` as

```
  List<String>  assetList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(asset));
```

Answer (score 1):

> it throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when i try to add
>   new element to it.

Because it returns **a fixed-size list**.

Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`
>
> ```
>      Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.
> ```

---

If you're consider adding or removing elements, you might be better off using a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

```
List<String> assetList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(asset));
```

Answer (score 1):

The resulting list coming from `Arrays#asList()` is defined [to be fixed size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).  This means that you can't add new elements to it.

If you want to get around it, wrap it in a new `ArrayList` instead:

```
List<String> assetList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(asset));
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). Arrays.asList() 'returns a fixed-size list'.

Answer (score 1):

For use in other methods that require a List  e.g. Collection.sort().

Check this [What is purpose of using asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891608/what-is-purpose-of-using-aslist)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can't be instantiated without passing size.
So when you initialize An array giving it's elements[indirectly passing size] and now you are converting it into an ArrayList using asList(arr[]) so this would result into an arraylist of fixed size that you can't modify.